# Can someone explain this strange systemverilog constraint behavior?

Tags: system-verilog

I am having hard time understanding this behavior with randomization in vcs simulation. can someone please help me?

```
class c;
  rand bit [31:0] base;

  constraint base_c {
    base +32'h40_0000 < 32'hFFFF_FFFF;
  }

endclass

module m;
  c c_obj = new();

  initial begin
    c_obj.randomize() with {
      base == 'hffe6_f6e2;
    };
  end
endmodule
```

I am not getting constraint error. base is of type bit which is unsigned. If I change the constraint as follows

```
constraint base_c {
  base < 32'hFFFF_FFFF - 32'h40_0000;
}
```

I get constraint error now. How does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple to work out the math here. All you need to do is plug in the values.

In the first case, you have

```
32'hffe6_f6e2 + 32'h40_0000 < 32'hFFFF_FFFF
```

which reduces down to

```
32'h0026_f6e2 < 32'hFFFF_FFFF
1'b1 // True
```

But when you have

```
32'hffe6_f6e2 < 32'hFFFF_FFFF - 32'h40_0000
```

This reduces down to

```
32'hffe6_f6e2 < 32'hffbf_ffff
1'b0 // False
```

It's not clear from your question what you are expecting, but you need to take underflow and overflow into account when writing constraints.

I just wrote a related blog post on these kind of math issues [here](http://go.mentor.com/verilog-in-constraints).